# How to extract rows from three tables

Tags: sql

I know to ask this question is not appropriate.

Student table - ID, Name, GPA

Class table - ID, Title, Semester

Student_Class table - Student_ID, Class_ID, Student_Grade

From this table structure, how to extract the student name who attended class.title = ‘MATH101’ and class.semester = ‘FALL2018’.

Without much research I got to ask this question. How can I make a start on this?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `WHERE`.

Comment: yes I know join and where but how to manipulate three tables is tricky to me

Comment: If you know how to join already, it is hard to understand what exactly it is you are having problems with.

Answer (score 4):

`Student_Class` is join table which implements many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Class`. So it just needed to join `Student_Class` with `Student` on `student_id` and `Student_Class` with `Class` on `class_id`.

```
select s.name
from Student s inner join Student_Class cs on s.id = cs.student_id
inner join Class c on cs.class_id = c.id
where c.title = ‘MATH101’ and c.semester = ‘FALL2018’.
```

Comment: I would guess the problem is a homework, and I am thus minded to think that a full answer won't help the OP, who needs to learn how to learn.

Comment: It is not a homework I can't tell the situation, this is very critical to me

Comment: Instead of inner join Student_Class cs on c.id = cs.student_id, should it be inner join Student_Class cs on c.id = cs.class_id?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: it should be Student s inner join Student_Class cs on s.id = cs.student_id. Answer was edited

Comment: @zanthia I appreciate your kind help, it means a lot to me

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the student name, so select from the student table. You only want to consider students who attended math in fall 2018, so add a where clause limiting the students accordingly.

This can achieved in various ways. One way to do this is

```
select name
from students
where id in
(
  select student_id 
  from student_class
  where class_id = 
  (
    select id
    from class
    where title = 'MATH101'
    and semester = 'FALL2018'
  )
)
order by name;
```

Another is

```
select name
from students s
where exists
(
  select null
  from student_class sc
  join class c on c.id = sc.class_id
  where sc.student_id = s.id
  and c.title = 'MATH101'
  and c.semester = 'FALL2018'
)
order by name;
```